# How to disable Navbar and footer in Yii2 other layouts

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, navbar, yii2-advanced-app

Is there any way to disable the navbar for `login` layout and `signup` layout in Yii2?

I've already deleted some codes like:

```
    <?php 
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
    ?>
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
```

and as all we know, `breadcrumbs` will disappear and seems good.But, What about the navbar and footer?

How can disable footer and navbar in Yii2 Application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a proper layout without the navbar and the footer and assign this layout before render the desired view

you can change layout this way

```
public function actionYourAction($id)
{


     $this->layout = 'yourNewLayout';

      return $this->render('yourView', [
       'model' =>$model,
      ]);
 }
```

the layout are in app\view\layouts

Comment: Exactly. Yii allows for infinite layouts so we can keep clean code.